# What steps to follow to run a cloned node.js web application?

Tags: node.js, web, github

There are many open-source web apps on github, when cloning one like:
https://github.com/wilfriedbarth/E-Commerce-App

What are the steps to get the app up and running on my local machine like command-line instructions and such (on a mac machine).

Thanks

Comment: Read the README file.  It's different for every application.

Comment: It's not mentioned there

Comment: That's how it goes.  You'll have to figure it out.  For this one, start with an `npm install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any node.js project, the `package.json` file contains a section called "scripts"

```js
...

  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },

...
```

So it seems like the author wants you to run `nodemon server.js`. You can do this by running:

```sh
npm run start
```

Comment: @Obaid90 if you are satisfied, please upvote this answer so it will mark it 'answered'